# wp_remote_post with file payload

Tags: wordpress

I'm attempting to POST a file through [wp_remote_post](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/http.php#L88). Unfortunately, any file stream, or file paths (prepended with CURL style @, or not), passed to this function are simply dropped and removed from the payload.

I found a post on [wp-hackers](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2013-January/045105.html), however, it's extremely hack-ish and error prone. Is there really no way to transmit a file through this function without writing a complete HTTP payload from scratch?

Here's an example code block using CURL style (prepending path with @), if interested:

```
    $body["attachment[{$i}]"] = "@{$attachment}";

    $data = array(
    'body' => $body,
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( "user:{$apiKey}" )));

$url = "https://api.someservice.net/{$domain}/endpoint";
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $data );
```

Thanks!

Comment: we need some error report/more info ... saying the payload is dropped isn't too descriptive, add if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
   echo 'Response:<pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
} and tell us what you get.

Answer (score -2):

Post data should be sent in the body as an array. Example passing post data:

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array(),
    'body' => array( 'username' => 'bob', 'password' => '1234xyz' ),
    'cookies' => array()
    )
);

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
   echo 'Response:<pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

In the example above, $response['body'] will contain the actual page content returned by the server.

Comment: please read the question before copy and paste directly from wordpress half baked docmentation. he is asking for file upload not data